# How to determine entity relationships for a proper noun

Tags: semantics, named-entity-recognition, ontologies

Apologies if I am using the wrong terminology

I am starting a pet project using R to determine the associations for a Proper Noun

For example I would like to see all the associations with the name 'Putin' expecting the associations to be everything from Russia, president,father and any other noun-based associations

Is this called ontological or semantic association and if so is there a specific terminology I could be directed to so I can look this up.

Comment: Is it a linguistic question or a computer programming question?

Comment: @amegnunsen Its a linguistic question about what type of linguistic analysis I should use for the intended outcome. It will eventually be computationally implemented

Comment: First of all, you have to decide what kind of proper nouns corresponds to your individual/classe. Because, Russia and Puttin are both proper nouns. Hence, if your class is the noun propers, you cannot realise relations between Russia and Puttin, they are individuals of a same class. So are you interested in personal name, toponyme, ... ?

Comment: Ok @amegnunsen is there a way of getting the toponym relation of proper nouns based on known association rather than presumed (ie not presuming Margaret Thatcher is from the UK because of the name but because she is a known figure)

Comment: **ISA** (or **isA**) **relationships** are all *copular*, but the 'be' verb may be hidden, in an apposition or parenthetical.

Comment: If I understand your words, it is not a linguistic question properly speaking,  but much more a identity perception question. Your problematic is how somebody can determine someone's nationality from textual elements or his background. It would be better to talk about referent instead of proper noun.

Comment: @amegnusen. OK Thanks. OK so I guess that is the question. How do I get the Nationality from referent. And the broader question is how to get weighted associations of a referent? Do you have any direction/ links for this?